# Multiple AJAX calls without blocking

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I run a function called `checker` every 60 seconds like so:

```
setInterval( checker, 60 * 1000 );
```

`checker` has an array of URLs which it checks via AJAX, the current code is like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: sites[i].url,
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "json",
  async: false,
  success: function(data){
     //blah blah blah
  }else{
     //something else
  },
  error: function(){
    //blah blah blah
  }
});
```

The code works, changes some UI based stuff depending on the results of the JSON. My problem is that the execution time for this checking several sites is ~4 seconds, at which point the page becomes unresponsive for this time. If I remove `async: false` the code no longer works as expected.

Someone mentioned using callbacks to solve the problem but don't understand how to use them in this context.

**EDIT**

Updated code based upon suggestion from adosan:

```
function promtest(){
    var sites = [
             { name: "WorkingSite", url: "http://sitename.com/testing.php" },
             //a bunch more sites, 1 returns a 404 to test for failure
             { name: "404Site", url: "http://404url.com/testing.php" }
             ];

    var promiseList = [];
    for(var i in sites){
    var promise = $.ajax({
    url: sites[i].url,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    async: true,
    success: function(data){

      if( data.Response != 'OK' ){
        console.log('Site ' + sites[i].name + ' Not OK' );
      }else{
        console.log( 'Site ' + sites[i].name + ' OK ');
      }
    },

    failure: function(data){
      console.log('Failure for site: ' + sites[i].name);
    },

    error: function(){
      console.log('Site ' + sites[i].name + ' Not OK' );
    }

    });

    promiseList.push(promise);
    }

    $.when.apply($, promiseList).then(function(){console.log('success')}, function(){console.log('fail')});

}
```

In the console I see:

```
Site 404Site Not OK
Site 404Site Not OK
Site 404Site Not OK
Site 404Site Not OK
Site 404Site Not OK
Site 404Site Not OK
Site 404Site Not OK
fail
Site 404Site Not OK
Site 404Site Not OK
Site 404Site Not OK
Site 404Site Not OK
```

Note that the site name is always showing as the last one on the list.

Comment: Please elaborate, what is not working when you remove the async: false setting.

Comment: Have you considered running it asynchronously (``async: true``)?

Comment: I don't think the code above really works... the *else* is outside of the function.

Comment: removing `async: false` or setting it to `true` and the console throws all sorts of errors, it looks as though because things may not return in order everything gets confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use Promise (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) here. Example:

```
function checker(url) {
    return new window.Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

        function successCallback(response) {
            resolve(response);
        }

        function errorCallback(response) {
            reject(response);
        }

        $.ajax({
            data: data,
            dataType: 'JSON',
            type: 'GET',
            url: url
        })
        .done(successCallback)
        .fail(errorCallback);
    });
}

function checkerSuccess(response) {
    console.log(response);
}

function checkerError(error) {
    console.warn(error);
}

checker('http://api.example.com').then(checkerSuccess).catch(checkerError);
```

Comment: This solution is much better than callbacks, while also non blocking, less code required, more maintainable. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery built in deferred mechanism (a promise).

https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

*jQuery.ajax* function does return a promise object which can be asigned to a variable.

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
 var promise = $.ajax({
      url: sites[i].url,
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      async: true
    });
```

The nice thing about promises is that you can combine multiple promisses into bigger one.

```
var promiseList = [];
promiseList.push(promise);
$.when.apply($, promiseList).then(function(){/*SUCCESS*/}, function(){/*FAILURE*/});
```

Complete code should look like so:

```
var promiseList = [];
for(var i in sites){
    var promise = $.ajax({
      url: sites[i].url,
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      async: true
    });

    promiseList.push(promise);
}
$.when.apply($, promiseList).then(function(){/*SUCCESS*/}, function(){/*FAILURE*/});
```

Comment: when I replace `$.when.apply($, promiseList).then(function(){/*SUCCESS*/}, function(){/*FAILURE*/});` with `$.when.apply($, promiseList).then(function(){console.log('success')}, function(){console.log('fail'});`, I have 10 sites, one of which should fail. I see each site return as expected in the 'network monitor', but the console contains a single 'fail', no successes for the ones which do work..

Comment: If I remove the test broken site from the list then I get 'success', so this method seems to only work if all sites return a working value. I need to be able to perform an action for each site in the list depending on it's status e.g. success or failure

Comment: The parrent promise does fail if any of the inner promise fails. If you want to  detect the failing site in your code, you should also add error handler to your ajax call:  error: function(data){console.log(sites[i].url + " has failed.")}

Comment: I've updated my question to show what I've tried and the output I get. I see the sites being called correctly in the 'network' tab of developer tools, but when using console.log, all the site[i].names being printed are the same?

Comment: It is caused by javascript's closure. Short explanation is that, during the execution time of your `success` or `error` function, the callback code sees current value of the `i` variable (which is 9 after for loop finishes). Try wrapping your ajax call with self executing function and pass the `i` variable as a parameter. Like so: `(function(i){  var promise = $.ajax(...);  })(i);`

Answer (score 0):

I would try this one.

Let's say that the object that you want to be updated is the var foo:

```
var foo = "";

$.ajax({
      url: sites[i].url,
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      async: false,
      success: function(data){

          foo = data.gottenValue1

      }else{
         //something else
      },
      error: function(){
        //blah blah blah
      }
    });
```